Are these kinds of bases for $\mathbb{F}_2^q$ seen as a vector space studied?
In the context of my research, I have to work with sets of vectors $\left\{y_i\right\}_{i\in[n+1]}$ of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ such that the following property is true:
$$\forall i\in[n+1], \left\{y_i\oplus y_j\right\}_{j\in[n+1]\setminus\{i\}}\text{ is a basis of }\mathbb{F}_2^n.$$
Note that we see here $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ as an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space with the addition being the bitwise XOR, just like when seeing it as a finite field. Its dimension is thus $n$.
More generally, in order to generate them in some programming language, the definition can be a bit generalized to "is a linearly independent family of vectors", if the set in question has less than $n+1$ elements.
Is this some well-known object, or a particular case of a well-known object?

I think $n+1$ such  vectors are said to be "in general position".

You're right @AndreasBlass . It's called in general linear position, where usually the basis is ${y_i - y_j}_{j \neq i}$

@AndreasBlass Thanks, this is what I was looking for! Can you add it as an answer so that I can accept it please?

Because this about $\Bbb{F}_2$ in particular I think your condition is equivalent to the original set of $n+1$ vectors being affinely independent..
